# Service with LocationListener

Tags: android, gps, android-service, locationlistener

My code is

```
    public class AlarmService extends Service implements LocationListener {
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        getLocation();
        if(reachedLocation()){
        Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(alarmIntent);
        stopSelf();
        }
@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        getLocation();
        if(reachedLocation()){
        Intent alarmIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(alarmIntent);
        stopSelf();
        }
}
```

onLocationChanged is never called. I have put the Minimum time between updates as 1 min. It is not called on 1 min and not when Locationchanged.

Comment: i think you forget to add  `@Override` before method

Comment: no the @override is already in the code

Comment: You edited in your question but you try in your code?

Comment: it was already in the code. i forgot to put it here.

Comment: After onStartCommand log shows
04-22 12:05:27.459: D/dalvikvm(666): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1115K, 58% free 2836K/6599K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 91ms

Comment: Have you mentioned your service in menifest?

Answer (score 0):

You have to request updates before you can get any by:

```
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Also, remember to add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION as a permission in your manifest

Comment: locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

is already written in the getLocation()
permissions are also set